# A New Simple Riley

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, english, acrostic

I have created another Riley in my down time today and I hope it is neither too easy, nor hard. As always, good luck to all of you, and have fun!

---

> I see the prefix, a letter you seek; look to the middle, take to I think.
>
> Now for the infix, look to the left; a veil with a crutch, I do attest.
>
> Finding the suffix, isn't really a chore; a noise you will shriek, when your face hits the floor.
>
> Overall in the present, but look to the past; if you want to learn more, simply just ask.

Comment: I'm glad someone is still doing Rileys. I never thought to do simple words, either,  (after seeing @El-Guest 's answer). I might give it another crack :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the word

> KNEW?

I see the prefix, a letter you seek; look to the middle, take to I think.

> The middle of this phrase has the letter K in both seeK and looK (taking two). If you take half the alphabet minus 2, you get the 11th letter K. It’s also present in thinK.

Now for the infix, look to the left; a veil with a crutch, I do attest.

> The left of this phrase has the letter N (which looks like a V with a crutch).

Finding the suffix, isn't really a chore; a noise you will shriek, when your face hits the floor.

> Just tried it a couple of times myself to check. OW. Actually the floor is kinda dirty. EW.

Overall in the present, but look to the past; if you want to learn more, simply just ask.

> You know things in present tense but you knew things in past tense. The acrostic spells INFO which is information that you knew. Also the title is a (k)new simple Riley.

Comment: Wow! Very fast +1 :D

Comment: Okay, I wish I could give +5 for that *Just tried it a couple times* comment. HAHAHA! Unfortunately this is not the correct answer; though you are on the right track! The title is a hint! :D I made this too easy.

Comment: To give perspective on the things you missed though (on top of what you've already found): rot13(x vf gur 11gu yrggre va gur nycunorg; jura lbh phg gur nycunorg va unys naq gnxr gjb lbh'er yrsg jvgu 11. Nyfb, x vf cerfrag va guvax. Irvy ba n pehgpu vf ersreevat gb n I ba n pehgpu abg gur ragver jbeq.)

Comment: @PerpetualJ so my prefix and infix are both correct somehow?

Comment: The final line is also a hint, especially the first half. The prefix, infix, and suffix are all correct for the intention. Though those are red herrings with the final line bringing you to your true destination.

Comment: There you go! I'll give the check when I can.

Comment: Ahh I see. It makes more sense now — I think the explanations are better too, thanks for explaining your intentions, I’ve added them!! :D